# PayPal Express Checkout always shows user "This transaction has expired." page, but no API error

Tags: php, redirect, curl, paypal

I'm trying to set up a simple payment sequence with PayPal's Express Checkout. My SetExpressCheckout call seems to work fine, I get `ACK=Success` and a token. When I redirect the user to PayPal using that token, though, it always displays a screen to them saying:

> This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website
>   to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.
>
> Your session has ended
>
> We're sorry, but your session has ended. Your account hasn't been
>   charged. Please go back to the merchant's site and check out again
>   with PayPal.

Just to clarify, I don't get any error codes from the SetExpressCheckout API call, but the token always seems to be expired. I've tried redirecting to nonsense tokens, but that generates a different page. It seems that I am both receiving a valid token and redirecting to it correctly, but it has always expired in the 1-2 seconds that that takes.

Details of an example request:

What I'm sending in the initial SetExpressCheckout request:

```
Array
(
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [useraction] => commit
    [RETURNURL] => xxxx
    [CANCELURL] => xxxxx
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 49.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 49.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => xxxxx
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => xxxxx
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => xxxxx
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 49
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [VERSION] => 74.0
    [USER] => xxxxx
    [PWD] => xxxxx
    [SIGNATURE] => xxxxx
)
```

Curl_getinfo about the request:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [content_type] => text/plain; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 255
    [request_size] => 798
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.139
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.187
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.64
    [size_upload] => 660
    [size_download] => 136
    [speed_download] => 119
    [speed_upload] => 579
    [download_content_length] => 136
    [upload_content_length] => 660
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.139
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 23.4.59.42
    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 192.168.0.102
    [local_port] => 63049
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

What I get back from PayPal via curl:

```
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-59031295261754641
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-01-20T10:12:27Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 84d3d68cbd574
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 74.0
    [BUILD] => 9285531
)
```

I'm then redirecting the user to the relevant URL for that token (with the token `urlencode`d), in this case:

```
https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=EC-59031295261754641
```

That all seems fine to me, but when I redirect to that URL, it always shows the 'transaction has expired screen'.

Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue, but my URL appears to match what the PayPal docs define.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem was that it was in Sandbox mode, and the redirection should be made to

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=`

Rather than the URL shown above.

This is shown on Page 36 of the [Express Checkout integration guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I also solved similar issue with removing paypal cookies. Problem was with changing sandbox account clientId/secret in the same browser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that removing the paypal cookies